# Latte Art... How much foam is too much foam?

Tags: latte-art

I've been a home coffee enthusiast for nearly 12 months now, so to cut a long question short, I'm pulling really nice & consistent espresso shots now after much experimenting & learning...but it's the latte art that is eluding me. I end up with what I think is way too much foam despite my attempts at keeping the stretch to a small amount. Does usually look smooth & silky at a good temperature & I my pouring is getting better all the time - but still the art will not show... Is it the milk?.. I'm only using supermarket bought full cream milk. Thanks !! :)

Comment: Hi, Steve. I can't tell what your actual question is, here. How much foam is too much is surely a matter of personal taste and it's not clear what problem you're attributing (possibly) to the quality of the millk.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally for latte art you should have zero foam in the conventional sense i.e. coarse foam or froth that has easily discerned bubbles. What you want to achieve is to make a completely homogeneous pitcher of *microfoam*.